# error occurred during a cryptographic operation .net framework 4.5.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, form-authentication

I am using angularjs and Web API. In order to authenticate user, I use FormAuthenticationTicket (I just create the ticket with user data, encrypt it and then return to the client).
When the client sends request he adds this encrypted cookie to the header of his request.

On remote server I decrypt the ticket, and verify if that user is legit.
On localhost it works perfectly.
on server I have an error, and after very short time the user is not identified.
after many debugging, I noticed that sometimes when the server tries to decrypt the ticket he gets exception: "error occurred during a cryptographic operation"

I googled this error, and from what I understood, the error is because the server tries to decrypt the ticket with another machine key.

thought maybe setting machine key in web.config will resolve the issue, but all the articles that I found were talking about early .net framework versions ( I am using 4.5.1).

This is when I get the error:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket fat = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(enc_ticket);
```

This is my web.config:

```
     <configuration><appSettings></appSettings>

      <system.web> <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <trust level="Full" />
  </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
          <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
          <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many research this is how I solved the problem:

[Generate the machine key here](http://www.a2zmenu.com/utility/Machine-Key-Generator.aspx)   and just add the machinekey values to web.config. This machine key will always be used on any of servers on webfarm where you hosting you website.